# Store system-generated PDF on S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, pdfkit

Solved, see edit at bottom.

---

In my 3.1 rails app I'm generating a pdf like this:

```
def show
  @contributor = Contributor.find(params[:id])

   respond_to do |format|
   format.pdf { 
    html = render_to_string(:action => "show.html.erb") 
    kit = PDFKit.new(html) 
    kit.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/stylesheets/unique/print.css" 
   thepdf = send_data kit.to_pdf, :filename => "blah.pdf", :type => 'application/pdf' 
redirect_to :action => save_to_s3      
}
end
```

Then I'm trying to store that generated PDF on S3 by uploading with Paperclip:

```
def save_to_s3
     html = render_to_string(:action => "show.html.erb") 
      kit = PDFKit.new(html) 
      kit.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/stylesheets/unique/print.css" 
      roy = Royarchive.new(:client_id => @contributor.client_id) 
      f = File.open("blah.pdf", 'w+')
      f.write kit.to_pdf
      roy.pdf = f
      roy.save!
end
```

But that's giving me `"\x9C" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8`

How can I use Paperclip to upload this generated pdf to S3? I'm using Heroku so I can't save a temp file on the server then upload it.

////solved

Oh, my bad, you *can* [store files for the duration of the session at root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625935/heroku-serving-large-dynamically-generated-assets-without-a-local-filesystem).

So this works:

```
   def show
  @contributors = Contributor.where(:client_id => current_user.client_id).paginate(:page => params[:page])
  @contributor = Contributor.where(:client_id => current_user.client_id).find(params[:id])


   respond_to do |format|
   format.html 
    format.pdf { 
    html = render_to_string(:action => "show.html.erb") 
    kit = PDFKit.new(html) 
    kit.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/stylesheets/unique/print.css" 
    send_data kit.to_pdf, :filename => "name.pdf", :type => 'application/pdf' 
    @thepdf = kit.to_file("#{Rails.root}/tmp/name.pdf")

roy = Royarchive.new(:client_id => @contributor.client_id) 
roy.pdf = @thepdf
roy.save!     
  }   

end
end
```

Comment: I will - you need more rep than I have to even answer, let alone accept, your own Q within 8 hours of writing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, my bad, you *can* [store files for the duration of the session at root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625935/heroku-serving-large-dynamically-generated-assets-without-a-local-filesystem).

So this works:

```
def save_to_s3
  html = render_to_string(:action => "show.html.erb") 
   kit = PDFKit.new(html) 
   kit.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/stylesheets/unique/print.css" 
  thepdf = kit.to_file("#{Rails.root}/tmp/name.pdf")

     roy = Royarchive.new(:client_id => @contributor.client_id) 
     roy.pdf = thepdf
     roy.save!
     redirect_to :action => index
end
```