# Upload a PDF copy of form to AWS S3 on Submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I currently have a large form that utilized the nested_form gem and I would like to add the functionality that on the "update" function it saves a pdf of the form to AWS's S3.

Currently I have implemented the PDFKit Gem and have the ability to generate a pdf by simply adding the .pdf extension to the path. For example.

```
/user/2/form/2

<%= nested_form_for(@user,@form) do |f| %>
  .....
  <%= f.fields_for :images do |i|%>
  .....
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and /user/2/form/2.pdf renders a pdf.

I have attempted to implement this functionality using Carrierwave to create a hidden :remote_image_url field and upload the .pdf remotely to s3 but this causes a timeout because the form is too large. I have attempted to use CarrierwaveDirect but from what I can tell there is no way to use the direct_form_for within the nested_form_for so I am unsure if I can implement the direct upload functionality.

I have begun exploring options using the AWS SDK for Ruby to just create a background process that could happen on save. However, I am struggling to find a methodology that allows me to save the file from the remote location.

Are there any alternatives that I have not yet considered? Any recommendations or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

//EDIT//

I am operating on Heroku which prevents the simplicity of just saving the file on the server. However, after reading a few articles [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269651/store-system-generated-pdf-on-s3). I am now going down the path of saving the file temporarily to the server using a model method before_save. And transferring it  directly to s3. Still unsure about the best method of getting the file from the server to aws S3 but at this point I am going to try using the AWS SDK for Ruby and see if I can make that work.

Comment: What about adding some JavaScript which is sending an AJAX call to your PDF-Rendering Controller method upon an action like pressing the submit button?

Comment: I think this is ultimately the best choice. At this point I am struggling more with what sort of code can I put in the controller to upload the file to s3 without a timeout error from server.